# I'm trying to listen to addliquidity event from uniswap router02

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js, uniswap

I'm trying to listen to addliquidity events to scrape newly added pairs data

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const NODE_URL = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/d3c5832256754c85be86b4c97de2d3d3"



const web3 = new Web3(NODE_URL);


const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D";
const CONTRACT_ABI = require('./abi.json');
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);

async function getEvents() {
    let latest_block = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
    let historical_block = latest_block - 10000; //change the value to 'latest' if you have a upgraded rpc
    console.log("latest: ", latest_block, "historical block: ", historical_block);
    const events = await contract.events.addLiquidity(
         
        { fromBlock: historical_block, toBlock: 'latest' }
    );
    await addLiquidity(events);
};

async function getaddLiquidityDetails(data_events) {
    for (i = 0; i < data_events.length; i++) {
        let address_tokenA = data_events[i]['returnValues']['address tokenA'];
        let address_tokenB = data_events[i]['returnValues']['address tokenB'];
            console.log("address tokenA:",address_tokenA,"address tokenB:",address_tokenB);
        }
    };



getEvents(CONTRACT_ABI, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
```

i got this error:  contract.events.addLiquidity is not a function

> I copied this code and havent fully edit it yet but i didnt expect this error event at this level
> source:https://ferhatkochan.medium.com/how-to-listen-to-smart-contract-events-with-web3js-345608f916c4

I double checked the abi and I found that the event addLiquidity exists, and i doubled check that the address is the right one using etherscan and indeed it is. and I checked the documentation of web3.js and it seems that there's nothing wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since you asked this question, but for other people who might come across this, the event is called Mint, not addLiquidity

https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/pair#mint

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34707033)